# Efficient parallel downloading and decompressing with matching pattern for list of files on server

Tags: bash, wget, gnu-parallel, bzip2

Every day every 6 hours I have to download `bz2` files from a web server, decompress them and merge them into a single file. This needs to be as efficient and quick as possible as I have to wait for the download and decompress phase to complete before proceeding further with the merging.

I have wrote some bash functions which take as input some strings to construct a URL of the files to be downloaded as a matching pattern. This way I can pass the matching pattern directly to `wget` without having to build locally the server's contents list to be then passed as a list with `-i` to `wget`. My function looks something like this

```sh
parallelized_extraction(){
    i=0
    until [ `ls -1 ${1}.bz2 2>/dev/null | wc -l ` -gt 0 -o $i -ge 30 ]; do
        ((i++))
        sleep 1
    done
    while [ `ls -1 ${1}.bz2 2>/dev/null | wc -l ` -gt 0 ]; do
        ls ${1}.bz2| parallel -j+0 bzip2 -d '{}' 
        sleep 1
    done
}
download_merge_2d_variable()
{
    filename="file_${year}${month}${day}${run}_*_${1}.grib2"
    wget -b -r -nH -np -nv -nd -A "${filename}.bz2" "url/${run}/${1,,}/"
    parallelized_extraction ${filename}
    # do the merging 
    rm ${filename}
}
```

which I call as `download_merge_2d_variable name_of_variable`
I was able to speed up the code by writing the function `parallelized_extraction` which takes care of decompressing the downloaded files while `wget` is running in the background. To do this I first wait for the first `.bz2` file to appear, then run the parallelized extraction until the last `.bz2` is present on the server (this is what the two `until` and `while` loops are doing).

I'm pretty happy with this approach, however I think it could be improved. Here are my questions:

- how can I launch multiple instances of `wget` to perform as well parallel downloads if my list  of files is given as a matching pattern? Do I have to write multiple matching patterns with "chunks" of data inside or do I necessarily have to download a contents list from the server, split this list and then give it as input to `wget`?
- `parallelized_extraction` may fail if the download of files is really slow, as it will not find any new `bz2` file to be extracted and exit from the loop at the next iteration, although `wget` is still running in the background. Although this never happened to me it is a possibility. To take care of that I tried to add a condition to the second while by getting the `PID` of `wget` running in the background to check if it's still there but somehow it is not working

```sh
parallelized_extraction(){
    # ...................
    # same as before ....
    # ...................
    while [ `ls -1 ${1}.bz2 2>/dev/null | wc -l ` -gt 0 -a kill -0 ${2} >/dev/null 2>&1 ]; do
        ls ${1}.bz2| parallel -j+0 bzip2 -d '{}' 
        sleep 1
    done
}
download_merge_2d_variable()
{
    filename="ifile_${year}${month}${day}${run}_*_${1}.grib2"
    wget -r -nH -np -nv -nd -A "${filename}.bz2" "url/${run}/${1,,}/" &
    # get ID of process running in background
    PROC_ID=$!
    parallelized_extraction ${filename} ${PROC_ID}
    # do the merging
    rm ${filename}
}
```

Any clue to why this is not working? Any suggestions on how to improve my code?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
I'm posting here my working solution based on the accepted answer in case someone is interested.

```sh
# Extract a plain list of URLs by using --spider option and filtering
# only URLs from the output 
listurls() {
    filename="$1"
    url="$2"
    wget --spider -r -nH -np -nv -nd --reject "index.html" --cut-dirs=3 \
        -A $filename.bz2 $url 2>&1\
        | grep -Eo '(http|https)://(.*).bz2'
}
# Extract each file by redirecting the stdout of wget to bzip2
# note that I get the filename from the URL directly with
# basename and by removing the bz2 extension at the end 
get_and_extract_one() {
  url="$1"
  file=`basename $url | sed 's/\.bz2//g'`
  wget -q -O - "$url" | bzip2 -dc > "$file"
}
export -f get_and_extract_one
# Here the main calling function 
download_merge_2d_variable()
{
    filename="filename.grib2"
    url="url/where/the/file/is/"
    listurls $filename $url | parallel get_and_extract_one {}
    # merging and processing
}
export -f download_merge_2d_variable_icon_globe
```

Comment: Probably [**rsync**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) was tried first? Then a kind of parallelized usage one might attempt. IMHO rsync has some technical features you are building yourself in part. Though I do not doubt your scenario requires some intelligent handling as you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you list the urls to download?

```
listurls() {
  # do something that lists the urls without downloading them
  # Possibly something like:
  # lynx -listonly -image_links -dump "$starturl"
  # or
  # wget --spider -r -nH -np -nv -nd -A "${filename}.bz2" "url/${run}/${1,,}/"
  # or
  # seq 100 | parallel echo ${url}${year}${month}${day}${run}_{}_${id}.grib2
}

get_and_extract_one() {
  url="$1"
  file="$2"
  wget -O - "$url" | bzip2 -dc > "$file"
}
export -f get_and_extract_one

# {=s:/:_:g; =} will generate a file name from the URL with / replaced by _
# You probably want something nicer.
# Possibly just {/.}
listurls | parallel get_and_extract_one {} '{=s:/:_:g; =}'
```

This way you will decompress while downloading and doing all in parallel.

Comment: yeah, that's a good idea. I tried to look up how was it possible to have a listing of the files directly within `wget` but could not find a good solution. I'm going to try this approach later and provide a MWE to show if it is working.

Comment: P.S. I think the `file` argument for `get_and_extract_one` is not necessary as if I don't specify it `wget` will use the filename and `bzip2` by default will just use the same without the `bz2` at the end...if I'm not mistaken. Right now I'm not specifying any file name for the output and everything's working wel..

Comment: @GuidoCioni The file argument is needed: `wget -O -` sends output to stdout, and we use this to decompress while downloading. In other words: `bzip2` starts decompressing _before_ the full file is fetched.

Comment: Thanks @Ole for the suggestion. I've made an update in the main question to show I used your suggestion to elaborate my working solution ;) Feel free to comment

Comment: Weird: if I call the function `download_merge_3d_variable` on just 1 variable at a time it works...but as soon as I'm trying to parallelize it by doing `variables=("V" "FI"); parallel -j ${N_CONCUR_PROCESSES} download_merge_3d_variable ::: "${variables[@]}"` something goes wrong: data is not downloaded at all for one variable and for the other data is incomplete. Does it have to do with the piping of data to stdout? For the variable that downloads 2D data instead this does not happen so it makes me wonder if it has something to do with the excessive number of files returned by `listurls`

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. The server was probably killing me for doing too many requests from the same IP. I solved it by putting a delay on the spawning of multiple jobs, i.e. `parallel --delay 2`.